# How to save my username or socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have chat with nodejs and socket.io.
I have this code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var username = socket.handshake.user.username;
    usersOnline.push(username);
    socket.broadcast.emit('join', username);
    io.sockets.emit('users', {users: usersOnline});

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        socket.broadcast.emit('leave', username);
        var index = usersOnline.indexOf(username);
        usersOnline.splice(index, 1);
        io.sockets.emit('users', {users: usersOnline});
    });
});
```

How  i can save my username that it no include to this userlist? Thak you

Answer (score 0):

I have array **people** `people[socket.id] = {"name": username};`
and get my username is `people[socket.id].name`